# Query SQL Database for Home and Away team based on Team ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm working on setting up a Football (Soccer) betting database using data from Betfair. This is my first ever Database and I'm working in MS SQL Server 2012.
I have set up 4 tables: Match, Team, Competition & Data.
My Match table contains columns: MatchID(PK), CompetitionID(FK), DateKickOff, TimeKickOff, TeamIDHome(FK), TeamIDAway(FK), ScoreHome, ScoreAway
My Team table contains columns: TeamID(PK), TeamName

I have been trying out some queries at this stage so that I can have a think about whether my tables are Normalised correctly. I wanted to run a query that would return 4 columns: Home Team Name, Home Score, Away Score, Away Team Name.

If I run this I get the first 3 columns back:

```
SELECT TeamName TeamH, ScoreHome, ScoreAway
FROM Match AS t
    INNER JOIN Team AS n
    ON t.TeamIDHome = n.TeamID
```

If I run this I get my fourth column:

```
SELECT TeamName TeamA
FROM Match AS t
    INNER JOIN Team AS n
    ON t.TeamIDAway = n.TeamID
```

But I cannot Union the 2 functions as I get an error: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
I believe that the error is caused because it tries to add the Away Team Names to the same column as the home team names. Can anybody suggest how I can query this correctly or let me know if I have a bad database design? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two queries for this. Add another join to Team linking the Match.TeamIdAway with team.TeamId. Like:

```
select HomeTeam.TeamName as TeamH, AwayTeam.Teamname as TeamA, M.ScoreHome, M.ScoreAway
from Match as M
join Team as HomeTeam on M.TeamIdHome = HomeTeam.TeamId
join Team as AwayTeam on M.TeamIdAway = AwayTeam.TeamId
```

Comment: Great thanks. Just what I needed. I guess I was mainly missing the 'as' command. You can tell its my first database...